# filter rows equal to a minimum value of a column

Tags: mysql

```
student(CNE,NameE,Age)
```

Delete all students who have a minimal age 
is this true ?

```
delete from student where CNE in(select CNE,MIN(Age) from student);
```

Comment: Delete students who have the min age?

Comment: Well as your inner select returns 2 different columns to an `IN()` which expects just a list of `CNE` values the query wont run

Comment: delete all students who have the min age

Comment: minimal age means what? `<20` or `<10`

Comment: if the min age is 11 years , delete all students who have 11 years

Comment: You will get an error, because the inner select returns two values instead of one.

Comment: And the inner select doesn't return the students with the minimum age, returns all the tuples for **ALL** the students with the CNE and the minimum age (the same value for all rows)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please keep in mind that this is an archive of good questions and answers.  Accordingly, please use a descriptive question title, and please describe your question with care.  (*Help* and similar words don't belong in titles.)

Answer (score 1):

In MySql you can't access directly the table from which you want to delete rows in a subquery in the `WHERE` clause.
So nest the subquery that gets the minimum age inside another subquery:

```
delete from student
where age = (
  select t.minage from (
    select min(age) minage from student
  ) t
)
```